# POST xml request using python

Tags: python, xml, post, request

I am new to python and I would like to automate an API using python using POST xml request to a destination URL.

Currently i am getting some errors in my program and i am not able to perform the activity.

My current code is as follows :

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
# Post XML to a web service and get XML results.
# For more robust HTTP error handler use FancyURLOpener
# E Begoli
import urllib
import httplibimport
import httplib
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
target_url = "http://TestLocation&pagesize=50"
xml_request = """\
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
      <<criteria>
    <includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
            Test
        <filterSet>
```

"""
    # sends xml request to url
    # with parameter request
    #
    def send_xml():
      result = urllib.urlopen( target_url, urllib.urlencode( {'request':xml_request} ) )
    #parse results and print the xml
    # or do whatever with it
    dom = parse( result )
    print dom.toprettyxml()
      result.close()
    def main():
    send_xml()
    if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

Comment: I suggest you use Requests library http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ which is easier than urllib

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa well as i am new to python so dont have much knowledge about all these stuffs. can you please modify the code for me as per your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I am lazy. If I were you I would just read Requests documentation, study it and rewrite the code using Requests library.

Comment: @user2260105 should should give us the error messages that you get.

Comment: @StephaneRolland actually while i am running the program then i am getting "cannot determine type" for "httplibimport".

Comment: @StephaneRolland is it possible for you to please modify the code for my requirements. I would be highly thankful to you.

Comment: You are missing a linebreak in that line, and need to at least try to understand your code before asking others to fix it for you.

Comment: @FredrikHåård Now i am getting the error at print dom.toprettyxml mentioned in my code.

Comment: "the error" ? "the" ? which one ? you do not tell us what is wrong. error message. precise information.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Error i am getting is Syntax Error: print dom.toprettyxml(): c:\Users\gulanand\Desktop\untitled-1.py, line 679
File "c:\Users\gulanand\Desktop\untitled-1.py", line 67, in ?
  print dom.toprettyxml()

Comment: instead try: `str_test = dom.toprettyxml()`  then on the line after `print str_test` if it's ever a problem with the dom module and its function toprettyxml(), which I really doubt there is. I suspect that's your indentation. You may have white spaces mixed with tabs. Python is really rude when not indenting thouroughly.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Actually i am not getting the significance of using print dom.toprettyxml()
  result.close()
def main():
send_xml()
if __name__ == "__main__":
main() part in my program

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":
main()` this is wrong, you don't have identation before main(). this part says: if the current instance of the script is main (self, you're calling the script directly `python myscript.py`) then this code is called. otherwise, when importing `import my_other_module`, the code if name == main is not called

Comment: builtins.ImportError: No module named 'httplibimport'
File "c:\Users\gulanand\Desktop\untitled-1.py", line 6, in <module>
  import httplibimport getting this error now

Comment: I don't have httplibimport either. maybe should be installed, or available from other module. i'm gonna see.

Comment: @StephaneRolland thanks.I tried to get that module but not getting some accurate documentation for that. If you please get the reference how to use it in my program please do suggest. Thanks

Comment: In the answer I have re-indented your code, that was obviously a copy-paste that has lost all indentation. It doesn't fix the httplibimport issue however.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Yess you are right. Now i am following the identation but this thing has not fixed the httplibimport issue

Comment: most probably you don't need `httplibimport` to execute only `urllib.urlopen()` . remove the `import httplibimport` and `import httplib`. when you know more about python look at `urllib2`. and the new way of doing things in python for http is python's `requests` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @StephaneRolland i has already tried to use import httplib but its not getting referenced to my current program. Please suggest how i would b able to use it in my program

Comment: remove it. the interpreter will say if the code really needs another module. the code you have posted doesn't seem to need another module. **only keep from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString and import urllib**

Comment: for using httplib http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html there are many examples at the bottom of that page for connections and POST and GET http messages

Comment: @StephaneRolland is there ant other way to perform what i am supposed to do using python

Comment: yep connecting to an url and retrive its content: `urllib2`. or the new python's standard for http that is `resquests`, but if it works with `urllib` alone just go on learning somthing else in python until you are at ease.

Comment: for parsing xml content, there are dozens of modules and 3rd party libraries. for really basic stuff i use minidom.xml. http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

Comment: @StephaneRolland Thanks for your responses. Actually i have some deadline to create this code.It will consume lot of efforts to go through the documentation. I would request you to please help me with the code development. thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are basically saying that you can't be bothered to learn and that random strangers on the internet should do your job for you?

Answer (score 1):

The almost first thing to learn in Python, it's identation.

```
def send_xml():
    result = urllib.urlopen( target_url, urllib.urlencode( {'request':xml_request} ) )
    #parse results and print the xml
    # or do whatever with it
    dom = parse( result )
    print dom.toprettyxml()
    result.close()

def main():
    send_xml()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```